# Defining get_queryset in a view, attribute error

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I'm trying to write a custom `get_queryset` function because I want to access the user's email from 'request.user.email', and use that to form another query, that i want to display using my view `cartv(generic.ListView)`. First time asking a question here, scoured the site but haven't found anything similar, but if you do find something just direct me there i''l delete this asap

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.24.169:8000/products/cart/

    Django Version: 3.1.2
    Python Version: 3.6.9
    Installed Applications:
    ['products.apps.ProductsConfig',
     'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles']
    Installed Middleware:
    ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nirman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/nirman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/nirman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nirman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nirman/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 142, in get
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
  File "/home/nirman/Desktop/login/products/views.py", line 91, in get_queryset
    self.user = request.user

Exception Type: AttributeError at /products/cart/
Exception Value: 'cartv' object has no attribute 'user'
```

views:

```
class cartv(generic.ListView):
    model = cart
    context_object_name = 'cart_list'   
    template_name='products/cartview.html'

    def get_queryset(request):
        qs = cart.objects.filter(user__email=request.user.email) #error points here
        if qs.exists():
            c = qs[0]
            return c.items.all()

        else:
            return redirect('failure')
```

models:

```
class cart_item(models.Model): 
products = models.ManyToManyField(product) 
quantity = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=1) 
user = models.ManyToManyField(User) 

class cart(models.Model): 
items = models.ManyToManyField(cart_item) 
user = models.ManyToManyField(User) 
ordered = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
```

Comment: `get_queryset` does not take a parameter `request`, the parameter is `self` Furthermore the `redirect` will not work in that case.

Comment: Can you share the `cart` and `item` model (the model where `c.items` refers to)?

Comment: Please [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass `self` parameter to `get_queryset` method. Then, within `self` parameter you can access `request` by `self.request`.

It should look like this in your case:

```
class cartv(generic.ListView):
    model = cart
    context_object_name = 'cart_list'   
    template_name='products/cartview.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = cart.objects.filter(user__email=self.request.user.email)
        if qs.exists():
            c = qs[0]
            return c.items.all()

        else:
            return redirect('failure')
```

Answer (score 0):

The [**`get_queryset(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) does not take a parameter `request`, it has a parameter `self` (like any object method).

Furthermore the `redirect` will not work in that case. A `get_queryset` should return a `QuerySet`, not a `redirect`. You can for example raise a `Http404` exception in this case:

```
from django.http import Http404

class cartv(generic.ListView):
    model = cart_item
    context_object_name = 'cart_list'   
    template_name='products/cartview.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        cart = cart.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        try:
            cart[0].items.all()
        except IndexError:
            raise Http404
```

It is however a bit "odd" to use `cart[0]` in the first place. If a user has multiple carts, then why return the first one?